# Does avconv have an equivalent complex filter for ffmpeg's adelay?

Tags: 14.04, ffmpeg, avconv

I have a working ffmpeg command to combine an audio/video file with an audio file, and I am now trying to perform the same operation using avconv on Ubuntu 14.04. My [ffmpeg command](https://superuser.com/a/1004471/483849) requires the use of the complex filter adelay:

```
ffmpeg \
-i video_and_audio.webm \
-i audio_only.webm \
-c:v copy \
-filter_complex '[1:a] adelay=2500|2500 [delayed]; [0:a] [delayed] amix [out]' \
-map 0:v \
-map '[out]' \
out.webm
```

Unfortunately this is a case where avconv and ffmpeg have different behavior; calling avconv with the same arguments produces this error:

`[AVFilterGraph @ 0x1426ca0] No such filter: 'adelay' Error configuring filters.`

Is there an avconv equivalent to this? Or do I need to install ffmpeg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Is there an avconv equivalent to adelay?

No. They haven't redesigned that wheel yet ([NIH syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here)).

See the rather short [list of `avconv` audio filters](http://libav.org/documentation/avconv.html#toc-Audio-Filters).

## Or do I need to install ffmpeg?

That is what I recommend. It's easy and you have several options (from easiest to hardest):

- [Get a static build](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/). Just download, extract, and execute. See below for more info.
- Use a PPA. See [Ubuntu Multimedia for Trusty 14.04](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media).
- [Compile](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu). You get the latest-and-greatest build and can customize to your liking.
- Upgrade your Ubuntu. FFmpeg returned in Ubuntu 15.04.

---

## Using the static build

You can use the static build like this (assuming it is in the `Downloads` directory):

```
/home/mattm/Downloads/ffmpeg -i input ...
```

or

```
~/Downloads/ffmpeg -i input ...
```

or to make it "just work" by just entering `ffmpeg` from anywhere you can add it to a directory that is included in your `PATH` environmental variable:

```
mkdir ~/bin
mv ~/Downloads/ffmpeg ~/bin
hash -r ffmpeg
. ~/.profile
```

To undo:

```
rm ~/bin/ffmpeg
hash -r ffmpeg
```